# Hatcher's exercise 1.2.22 on the Wirtinger presentation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928930/obtaining-wirtinger-presentation-using-van-kampen-theorem) exercise 1.2.22 is recalled, but the asker seems to know how to solve it assuming the "geometry is valid". I however, do not know to use the van Kampen theorem in order to find the relations $x_ix_jx^{-1}_i=x_k$ that Hatcher describes. I would like some assistance with this - my geometric intuition is pretty bad.

Comment: Use Proposition 1.26

Comment: @PVAL that much I figured, but I don't see how to get the actual relation described because I can't visualize anything :\

Comment: Here's a [visual proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563549/what-is-the-abelianization-of-pi-1-mathbbr3-setminus-k-where-k-is-a-k/1568603#1568603) of the Wirtinger presentation. You can make that rigorous by appropriate application of SvKT.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture taken from [Out of Line](http://www.groupoids.org.uk/outofline/motion.html#motion) "Paths and Knot Spaces"

[image: relcross]

There is more discussion at [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) p,350,  and this  simple crossing diagram in some sense assumes one is using the **fundamental groupoid**: insistence on one base points is not natural to the knot situation.

I have demonstrated the crossing relation to children  using  a copper pentoil and rope, 
and ended up with this string wrapping on the pentoil:

[image: pentwrap]

and asking one of the children to show how the loop comes off the knot!